# Place section title on left of text in "seperate column"

Tags: formatting

I found this resume, and am trying to recreate something similar using latex.
The section title is on the left, in its own column, but it's not on the edge, leading me to believe it's not in the margin. How could I accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following template:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in,left=2in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\newheading}[1]{% Insert a heading
  \par% End off the previous paragraph, if there was one (and enter vertical mode)
  \addvspace{.5\baselineskip}% Insert a gap
  \leavevmode% Leave vertical mode (to start setting the paragraph
  \llap{\bfseries\sffamily #1\hspace*{1em}}% Set the heading in the margin; 1em space on the right
  \ignorespaces% Ignore spaces following \newheading{...}
}
\newcommand{\subheading}[1]{% Insert a subheading
  \ifvmode% If in vertical mode...
    \addvspace{.5\baselineskip}% ...add some vertical space
  \fi
  {\bfseries #1}% Set the subheading...
  \par% ...and end off the paragraph
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indent

\begin{document}

\sffamily

\newheading{Skills}
\subheading{Graphics Programming / Software Engineering / Machine Learning}
Proficient in: C++, Vulkan, Python, TensorFlow, PyTorch, Pandas, JavaScript, React

\subheading{Communication}
Presented at companies and conferences including Microsoft, Amazon, and Web
Summit to audiences of 200+ people on my work with machine learning

\newheading{Competencies}
\subheading{Graphics Programming / Software Engineering / Machine Learning}
Proficient in: C++, Vulkan, Python, TensorFlow, PyTorch, Pandas, JavaScript, React

\subheading{Communication}
Presented at companies and conferences including Microsoft, Amazon, and Web
Summit to audiences of 200+ people on my work with machine learning


\end{document}
```